# How much time passed from the end of season 5 to the Battle of the Bastards?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I know the showmakers don't tell the time in *Game of Thrones*, but I believe an estimate can be done on how long it would take for all their travels.

So from the day Theon/Reek and Sansa Stark (Sansa Lannister? Sansa Bolton?) escape the Boltons, to the day of the Battle of the Bastards, how long has it passed?

There are accurate maps of westeros in the web, and the average miles per day of their choice of transportation is also well-known.

It is not concerned with whether the timelines shown are simultaneous or not. Focus only on the Starks movements in the North.

Comment: I saw an analysis that worked it out as around 5-6 months (i.e. long enough to conclude that Sansa's not pregnant) but that was based on the faulty assumptions that the different characters' stories happen in parallel. Best time indication I can think of for Sansa's story in isolation is to add time for her to reach the wall (days) + time for army to march toward Winterfell and leaders to tour Northern lords (weeks/months) + time for one Sansa at the wall to sew herself and Jon entire Stark-themed winter wardrobes plus a castle's worth of Stark banners (6-8 weeks?)...

Comment: @user568458 was that the Jason Concepcion Ringer article I quoted in http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55793/what-did-ramsay-actually-mean/55801#55801?  It's not exactly the same amount of time for all characters' stories, but based on when characters in different locations hear about each other, I think we can assume it's relatively close.  Especially because Littlefinger keeps riding back and forth between show locations.  (Eyrie to Winterfell to Kings Landing to the Eyrie to Moat Cailin to the Wall to Moat Cailin to Winterfell).

Comment: @Kuhl Looks like I'd already upvoted that answer, so I guess so! Why not adapt it into an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

The time is on the novel is pretty confusing too, once it is relative to each of the characters. On the show, well, it's like you said. But let's think this through.

Sansa went to castle black, and then they came riding down north from the wall getting all kinds of help from the Lords of the North. Usually, in the books, a travel to a place relativaly close take days-weeks. That depends, if you're riding north from the south, it'll take you 2 months (like said on the first season). That is if you're riding with a party (like jon and sansa was). So, I estimate, one week to each of the encounterings + the days they spent on each house as guests, + the riding right down to strike Winterfell, + the time they had to plan the attack.

I don't think it as long as 6 months, if you isolate Sansa's and Jon's story. But it surely wasn't fast either. The time in between season 5 and The Battle of The Bastards is about **2-3 MONTHS**, taking count of all of the events (based on the books and show) and isolating Sans's and Jon's story.